# How to convert pandas dataframe to a table with Column==value columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic

Since I don't know the name of the concept I am looking for, googling it has made but no success...

I need to convert something like:

```
   a   b        c   d
   1   2    'Hey'   4
   2   2  'Hello'   4
   1   2  'World'   3
```

to something like:

```
   a==1  a==2  b==2  c=='Hey'  c=='Hello'  c=='World'   d==3    d==4
      1     0     1         1           0           0      0       1
      0     1     1         0           1           0      0       1
      1     0     1         0           0           1      1       0
```

I am using python 3.8 and pandas 1.1.3
Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with convert all values to strings and set `prefix_sep` parameter:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str), prefix_sep='==')
print (df)
   a==1  a==2  b==2  c=='Hello'  c=='Hey'  c=='World'  d==3  d==4
0     1     0     1           0         1           0     0     1
1     0     1     1           1         0           0     0     1
2     1     0     1           0         0           1     1     0
```